# Magento - programmatically save static block content

Tags: php, magento, static-block

I have a static block that I would like updating by a script which gets run via cron.

I've found out how to create or retrieve a block programmatically, but not how to edit an existing one.

This works to retrieve a block:

```
// Retrieve the layout object
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout');

// Generate a CMS block object
$block = $layout->createBlock('cms/block');

// Set the block ID of the static block
$block->setBlockId('my_block_id');

// Write the static block content to screen
echo $block->toHtml();
```

I think I'm missing something simple here, but doing setContent() and then save() on this block just results in "Invalid method Mage_Cms_Block_Block::save"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By block id:

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($id)
  ->setData('content', 'Example content')
  ->save();
```

By identifier:

```
Mage::getModel('cms/block')
  ->getCollection()
  ->addFieldToFilter('identifier', 'my_block_id')
  ->load()
  ->setData('content', 'Example content')
  ->save();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$identifier = 'footer_links';
Mage::getModel('cms/block')
    ->load($identifier, 'identifier')
    ->setData('content', 'Your new block content')
    ->save()
;
```

Or if you know the block id:

```
$id = 1;
Mage::getModel('cms/block')
    ->load($id)
    ->setData('content', 'Your new block content')
    ->save()
;
```

Comment: Thanks, this works great, diNord just beat you to the answer though so I will give him the accept!

Answer (score 0):

Update and add static block using magento scripts

```
function createBlock($blockData) {

$block = Mage::getModel('cms/block')->load($blockData['identifier']);
$block->setTitle($blockData['title']);
$block->setIdentifier($blockData['identifier']);
$block->setStores(array($blockData['storeId']));
$block->setIsActive($blockData['active']);
$block->setContent($blockData['content']);
$block->save();
```

}

please refer my blog for step by step explanation

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-create-and-update-the-static-blocks-using-magento-script/